# java jdom edit xml file

Tags: java, xml, jsp, jdom

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import= "org.jdom.*, java.util.*, 
org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder,org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter,java.io.*" %>


<%
  SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
  Document doc = saxBuilder.build("http://localhost:8080/cPEP_UI/config.xml");
%>

<html>
  <head><title>Configuration Manager</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1><font color='green'>Configuration Manager</font></h1>
    <%! private String type;
    Element childNode;
    Element create;
    Element parent;
    %>

      <%
      List list = doc.getRootElement().getChildren();
      Iterator iter = list.iterator();

      while (iter.hasNext()){
        Element element = (Element) iter.next();
        List NameDOBCity  = element.getChildren();

        Iterator listIter = NameDOBCity.iterator();
      %>

      <%
        while ( listIter.hasNext() ){
           childNode = (Element) listIter.next();
         String param = request.getParameter(childNode.getName()+childNode.getAttributeValue("id"));

          Enumeration e = request.getParameterNames();
          while(e.hasMoreElements()){
              String s = (String)e.nextElement();
              if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(childNode.getName()))
                  childNode.setText(param);
          }

      %>       




      <%

        }


      }

      XMLOutputter xmlOutputter = new XMLOutputter();
      xmlOutputter.output(doc, new FileWriter("E:/workbench j2ee/cPEP_UI/WebContent/config.xml"));
      %>



  </body>
</html>
```

** whats wrong with the code?! Its not showing any error, but not changing the element text either. Actually I am making an gui, and need to edit config.xml using textbox in jsp.

Comment: I am trying to edit existing xml file using jdom and then saving it. I am allowing users to edit it using html components like textbox etc. Please help me with this thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the Filewriter using `FileWriter.close()` could help...

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("E:/workbench j2ee/cPEP_UI/WebContent/config.xml");
xmlOutputter.output(doc, fileWriter);
fileWriter.close();
```